# How to recover Bitcoin mistakenly sent to a bch address

Tags: transactions

A few days ago I could not open my btc.com wallet so I went to Google play and downloaded a bch wallet after the search for Bitcoin showed me this. So naturally I thought this to be a btc wallet. It gave me a receive address that I gave to CoinMama for a purchase of Bitcoin. The funds didn't show up in my wallet. How do I access these funds now?

Answer (score -1):

bch and btc use the same type addresses. try importing the private key into the wallet

Comment: Okay I don't know what a private key is. I have a paper key if that helps. Or could you tell me how to access my private key on unit wallet?